# WP_Query multiple value not working

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, meta-value

How to query for multiple meta key values with the same key
i have this query but multiple value not working for me, Where is my code wrong?

```
if( isset( $_POST['scheduled_scan'] ) && $_POST['scheduled_scan'] == 'on' )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'antivirus_antivirus_featured_scaning',
            'value' => array('scheduled_scan','anti_spyware','anti_worm'),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
```

[this is a full code in my form and query if you need](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371213/wp-query-with-many-meta-query-arguments-taking-a-long-time-to-load)

i used the advanced custom fields for keys

thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` with an array of multiple values. What does the value of `antivirus_antivirus_featured_scaning` look like?

Comment: `antivirus_antivirus_featured_scaning` is a checkbox field and i tried with `'='` but not work i used advanced custom fields plugin

Comment: This query will be quite slow, if `antivirus_antivirus_featured_scaning` had been a custom taxonomy then this query would see massive performance gains, as well as free archives and templates for thse terms. If you're using ACF then it's a simple switch to tell ACF those fields are saved as terms in a custom taxonomy

Comment: @TomJNowell how to do ?

Comment: I answered your other question, but you didn't ask about performance in this question, I won't derail the comments or post an unrelated answer here. You'll need to consult the ACF documentation for how to use taxonomies instead of post meta for a field ( and register a custom taxonomy for it to use to store the data )

Answer (score 0):

This is waaaay after the fact, but maybe it'll help someone else. You're looking for an IN comparison here - where the value is IN a group of values.

Here's what it'd look like:

```
$args['meta_query'][] = [
    'key' => 'antivirus_antivirus_featured_scaning',
    'value' => ['scheduled_scan','anti_spyware','anti_worm'],
    'compare' => 'IN'
];
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters =]